# cakePHP dynamicaly adapting input JqueryUI suggestions how?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm trying to do input suggestions. This in It's self is nothing special JqueryUI is able to that pretty much out of the box...

where I ran into trouble was by providing jqueryUI with a list of possible suggestions you need to provide... the Table I use is to Big do be dumped as a whole into the view... but I can't figure out how to thake the value from as the user starts to type into the field and give him the first 100 suggestions that remain...
with this I hope to reduce the load on the DB and speed up loadtime of the page because CakePHP doesn't have pack the whole table into the view each time a User requires the form!

the Code I have so far: (every helping hand is much appreciated! thx...)
Controller:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class LocationsManagerController extends AppController {
public $helpers = array('Js');
public $components = array('RequestHandler');
public function index() {

}

public function updateSuggestions() {
    /*
     * place passed Value into $locationName
     */
    $this -> loadModel('Location');
    if ($this -> RequestHandler -> isAjax()) {
        $this -> Location -> find('list',array(
            'limit'=>'100',
            'conditions' => array('Location.name' => $locationName),
        ));
        $this->render('suggestions');
    }
    /*
     * tell JqueryUI to update it's suggestion Array...
     */

}
```

}
?>

View:
index.ctp

```
<div id="suggestions">
<!--
array of possible Options...
-->
</div>
<?php
echo $this -> Html -> script('jqueryUI', FALSE);
echo $this -> Form -> create('locationsmanager');
echo $this -> Form -> input('Location', array('id' => 'location'));
echo $this -> Form -> submit('Send');
$updateSuggestions = $this -> Js -> get('#location') -> event(
#@formatter:off ; 
'change',
$this->Js->request(
    array(
        'action' => 'foo', 
        'data' => $form, 
    ),
    array(
        'async' => true, 
        'update' => '#suggestions'
    )
)
#@formatter:on ;
);
?>
```

is this the best method to do this? thx for your help!!

Comment: You need a counter that counts first 3 or 4 characters and then retrieves from the database?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jueryUI you can use autocomplete:

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

then in your controller you have to create an action that returns a json list of your suggestion.